# Selenium: a strange issue for select an iframe

Tags: selenium-rc

I am testing a web page with iframe using Selenium1 (C#). I used a line like "selenium.SelectFrame("relative=up");" (before selecting the iFrame), but it always failed at the first 2 times but succeeded after that. Although I could use try-catch to walk around it, i really hate the current approach. Anyone know what happened on the Selenium Server?

The error is like:

Test threw exception:  Selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: There was an unexpected Alert! [There is a problem with the server method that has been called. Please contact Technical Support if this error persists.].

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with SelectFrame().  Any Selenium command you use at this point will fail.  The problem is that your application has popped up an alert.  Selenium captured it, and requires your test script to confirm that the alert was expected by retrieving it (via GetAlert()).  The alert is the text between the brackets in the exception - in this particular case, `There is a problem with the server method that has been called. Please contact Technical Support if this error persists.`

Based on that, I'd say your test has detected a failure in the application - congratulations!  Report it to the developers and be happy :-)